# How to escape pipe character in Pattern.compile()

Tags: java, regex

I have problem with escaping of pipe (|) character when I using Patter.comile(). 
I have the code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Scratch {

    static String finPatternWithPipe() {
        String text = "123|FirstName=First|SecondName=Second|567";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("FirstName=(.*)\\|");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratch.finPatternWithPipe();
    }
}
```

And want to receive result "**First**" but actual result is "**First|SecondName=Second**".
If I change code and instead regexp "*FirstName=(.*)\|*" use "*FirstName=(.*)\|**S***" so the result will be such as I expected "**First**". 
What is my problem? I want to use pipe character like a last character which I want to see in my regexp string but don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Use `([^|]++)`. It’s usually better (faster, more obvious) to describe what you _don’t_ want to match.

Comment: @BoristheSpider or don't use regex: find the first name with `indexOf`, find the following pipe with `indexOf`. I'd bet that's a lot faster (but more verbose).

Comment: @AndyTurner I hesitate to recommend hand rolling string parsing. In my experience this pours concrete onto what is usually a fairly flexible situation. The hours I’ve spent tweaking these sorts of hand rolled parsers when format changes I’ll never get back... Although you’re right of course - if performance is a concern then Regex is slow. My comment was more about fast Regex than fast.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I feel your pain. I think it is always worth pointing out that regexes are not the only way to process strings, though.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thank you! It's interesting way to solve the problem. I will use it also in my work. But the answer by Andy below ("to make the quantifier non-greedy") is more clear for me in such case.

Comment: @Costonied think what the logic has to do. It’s just faster, if each iteration can just check whether the current character is inside a group. The lazy wildcard approach must, after for each character, check the _rest of the pattern_ to see if it matches. If it doesn’t, it must backtrack the rest of the pattern and advance with wildcard. In the general case, wildcards are bad news - lazy ones are better than greedy ones, but they’re all bad news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the quantifier non-greedy:

```
Pattern.compile("FirstName=(.*?)\\|")
                              ^ add this
```

Otherwise, the `.*` matches as much as it can, which includes pipe characters.